# Copy a ROS Installation between two systems

Tags: robotic-arm, compile, ros-kinetic, build, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there, I am working with ROS Kinetic right now. I build ROS on a ARM based unit.
Is it possibly to "copy" my current ros installation, as is and move it to another ARM board?
Is there a  list of all folders ROS installs in?
Whtat is the preferd way to target this?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283433/copy-a-ros-installation-between-two-systems/) by [Peter1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33821/peter1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2018-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-02-22**:
It really depends on how you've installed ROS.

**Comment by [Peter1](https://answers.ros.org/users/33821/peter1/) on 2018-02-26**:
Can you eleborate on that? I install ros from the repository. The main folder is installed in the opt directory. But I dont know where to look up all additional installation folders apart from opt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might not be what you're looking for, but usually when I do that I just copy the whole system using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2018-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1